# How to use next-iron-session with custom api route middleware in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm using  next-iron-session for session storage and firebase for auth, every api route should have auth middleware and also  next-iron-session, it my first time using NextJS.
tried a few different ways but none of them works, here is what I did so fare:

```js
//auth-middleware.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { auth } from "utils/firebase-admin";
import { sessionObject } from "utils/session";
import { withIronSession } from "next-iron-session";

const withAuth = (handler: any) => {
  return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const { accessToken } = (<any>req).session.get("user");

    await auth.verifyIdToken(accessToken);

    return handler(req, res);
  };
};

export default withIronSession(withAuth, sessionObject);
```

```js
//hello.ts (just a simple route)
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import authMiddleware from "utils/auth-middleware";

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe" });
};

export default authMiddleware(handler);
```

I am not sure is it the correct way or not.

any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an additional closure around your `withIronSession` function call to pass the `handler` function to `withAuth`.

```js
// auth-middleware.ts

export default function authMiddleware(handler: any) {
    return withIronSession(withAuth(handler), sessionObject);
};
```